# phpBB3 - creating forum categories

Tags: php, forum, categories, phpbb3

I want to automate the process of creating a forum category with the phpBB library. I know how to post topics and forums by using the `submit_post()` function but I don't know how you make the forum into a category in which more forums/topics can be added.

`submit_post()` function: http://wiki.phpbb.com/Function.submit_post

There is no mention in the documentation here about making the forum into a category, so I'm assuming there is a different function for that.

To create a forum category in the ACP you'd go to create new forum, enter the name, and select category from the **Forum Type** drop-down list. However there is no definition of forum type in the function above, so I assume its a different function.

Having some trouble tracking it down though. If anyone knows the function I need please share.

Comment: What does the automation process require to make the auto cats.
e.g: an RSS feed to Cat/forum/post.
This is to help me understand what you will require within phpBB.
You can bypass the ACL auth and make a file to automate this process with snippets from ACP_FORUMS class but it depends how you want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution here. It requires writing directly to the database in places but does utilize some of the phpBB library classes: http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=758985

I did find an alternative which is purely phpBB library classes: http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1289975

However this second solution requires you to have a 'System' user setup, which wouldn't work with the implementation I have. As I assume the system user would need to be authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/djsmix/SFNC

You can always check this mod for rss to forum topic.

in the includes/mods folder open smixmods_feed_news_center.class.php
and scroll down to `private function init_posting()`
you can examine that code to find how to make your own type of automated forum cat bot.